# How do I run Selenium tests in a Chrome browser managed by my company

Tags: macos, selenium, google-chrome

We are busy switching our Selenium tests to use the Chrome driver instead of Firefox. Chrome is managed by the company so when the tests run it opens up on a screen that forces you to log into a Chrome profile:

[image]

How would I bypass this for the tests?

Running it in headless mode, disabling extensions and setting a different user directory does not work.

Comment: Not sure but have you tried adding your profile to selenium - example `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path to your chrome profile` ?

Comment: @0m3r I need to log in even when setting my user directory to my own Chrome profile's directory. The tests do run after that, but that isn't really a feasible testing environment

Comment: Couldn't find any solution for this. I ended up using Brave and the Selenium Chrome driver since this seems like the closest option to Chrome.